# What is the difference between 'qr' and 'SVD' in Matlab to get the single vectors of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, calculus

Spefifically, the following two kinds of code can get the same S and V idealy. However, the second one's speed is usually faster than the first one in Matlab. Can someone tell me the reason? 
Moreover, which method is more numerically stable?
Thanks.

```
[~,S,V] = svd(B,'econ');


[Qc,Rc] = qr(B',0);
[U,S,~] = svd(Rc,'econ');
V = Qc*U;
```

Comment: This is more  a maths question. SVD and QR are used for more things than getting the singular vectors, for example, SVD is common to solve `Ax=B` type of equations. So for some specific things (im not a mathematician) SVD and QR can get to the same place, I assume

Comment: It is not a difference "in Matlab", it is a difference in the math theory. I am not an expert in this domain but maybe you could read this to get an idea of the differences: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos323/notes/cos323_f11_lecture09_svd.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method does not have to be faster. For almost squared matrices it can be slower. Consider as example the Golub-Reinsch SVD-algorithm:

Its work depends on the output you want to calculate (only `S`, `S`and `V` or `S`,`V` and `U`).

If you want to calculate `S`and `V` without performing any preprocessing the required work is *4mn^2+8n^3*.

If you perform QR-decomposition before this the needed amount of work is: *2/3n^3+n^2+1/3n-2* for the Housholder transformation. Now if your Matrix was almost squared, i.e m=n, you will have gained not much as R is still m x n. However **if m is larger than n you can reduce R to an n x n matrix (called thin QR factorization)**. Now you want to calculate `U`and `S` which will add *12n^3* for your SVD-algorithm.

So only SVD: *4mn^2+8n^3*

SVD with QR: *(12+2/3)n^3+n^2+1/3n-2*

However most SVD-algorithms should inculde some (R-) bidiagonalizations which will reduce the work to: *2mn^2+11n^3*

You can also apply QR, the R-bifactorization and then SVD to make it even faster but it all depends on your matrix dimensions.

Matlab uses for SVD the Lapack libraries. You can look up the exact runtimes [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521036). They're approximately the same as above algorithm.

Hope this helps.